# Search based on filters using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

[image]

I am working on SharePoint 2010, I have a custom list with columns Start date , End date, Created by, Approval Status.
I have created a page where I am looking to filter the list and show the result depending on the approval status which is a column in custom list as shown in figure . Can some one help me out on how to approach for this.

Answer (score 2):

I just did something similar for SharePoint 2013 but I'm pretty sure this works for 2010 as well.

You can pass in special query string parameters to your views on a list, namely **FilterFieldN**, **FilterValueN**, and **FilterOpN** (where N is a number between 1 and 10).

Example: **http://example.com/lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=your_filter_value&FilterOp1=Contains** should return all items from the Task list where Title contains "your_filter_value".

You can string up to 10 of these together on a given request.

What you can do is use your jQuery in a Content Editor Web Part that will build the URL containing the filter values (like the example above) and then redirect them to that page/view.

The advantage of this approach is it is straight forward, non-intrusive, and leverages functionality SharePoint already has built-in.

Comment: hi mcgrath the link you have provided is not working can you provide with alternate link Thanks.

Comment: The link is just an example :)

Comment: Apreciate if you could provide any snippet for the same ...Thanks